# Saying "Hello" at the beginning of a question/answer

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if there is a bug regarding the form of the questions and answers.
Often I begin a question or an answer with "Hello..." and I notice that when I post it, it gets cut off. Is there a reason for this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i.e. in this question I wrote "Hello community", for instance.

Comment: Indication that a question may have been  asked by a human being doesn't bother me a whole lot. Perhaps I am too insensitive.

Comment: @Andre: You wouldn't pass the reverse Voight-Kampf test like that. :-)

Comment: @AndréNicolas: _Every_ question on the site "may have been asked by a human being," regardless of whether additional noise has been added to it.

Comment: Further, a machine capable of posting questions here should also be able to add some pseudo-salutation.

Comment: Does the software nail you if you start a question with "H3110"?

Comment: Ha! I'll try that next time :)

Comment: You could also try "01134" and then turn your screen upside down.

Comment: @JacobBond: Or $07734\ldots$ :-$)$

Comment: I think I'll just begin with "Well be with you, gentlemen"...

Comment: I would like to be able to start my question like a sir but mathstack does not allow me

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, greetings are automatically removed when they are detected. As [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) says:

> #### Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.

(It really should say [or greeting] in the last sentence; an omission of the help center writer.)

One of reasons to cut out (and otherwise discourage) the greetings is that the beginning of a post is what one sees in [search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=analytic%20maps). I'd much rather see

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on a disk $D$ and the image of every horizontal line segment is a horizontal line segment...

than

> Dearest Users of Mathematics Stack Exchange,
> I am a long-time reader, first time poster.
> This question may be easy but I am stuck. It sa...

---

Generally, I recommend stating the question first, and adding any background information (thoughts, partial results, your background, motivation for the question... as applicable) after it.

Comment: Your search result argument just converted me to your position. Very good point.

Comment: Gosh, makes me want to try and work around it...